# Display buttons one by one

Tags: xaml, windows-8.1

I have the four buttons:

```
<Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Style="{StaticResource launchButton}" Content="1" x:Name="b1" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
<Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource launchButton}" Content="2" x:Name="b2" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
<Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Style="{StaticResource launchButton}" Content="3" x:Name="b3" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
<Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource launchButton}" Content="4" x:Name="b4" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
```

I need to display them one by one.  I have done it by this code:

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    Display();
}

public async Task Display()
{            
    b1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(300));
    b2.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(300));
    b3.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(300));
    b4.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}
```

But I am wondering is there any better solution? May be a pure XAML approach ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about an `EventTrigger` in the enclosing Grid (where the RoutedEvent defaults to `Loaded`)?

`Visibility` is replaced by `Opacity` because that is easily animatable by a DoubleAnimation, and I've added an initial delay of one second, because otherwise it's too fast for me to notice.

```
<Grid.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger>
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
                <DoubleAnimation
                    Storyboard.TargetName="b1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                    To="1" Duration="0:0:0" BeginTime="0:0:1"/>
                <DoubleAnimation
                    Storyboard.TargetName="b2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                    To="1" Duration="0:0:0" BeginTime="0:0:1.3"/>
                <DoubleAnimation
                    Storyboard.TargetName="b3" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                    To="1" Duration="0:0:0" BeginTime="0:0:1.6"/>
                <DoubleAnimation
                    Storyboard.TargetName="b4" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                    To="1" Duration="0:0:0" BeginTime="0:0:1.9"/>
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
</Grid.Triggers>
<Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Content="1" x:Name="b1" Opacity="0"/>
<Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Content="2" x:Name="b2" Opacity="0"/>
<Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Content="3" x:Name="b3" Opacity="0"/>
<Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Content="4" x:Name="b4" Opacity="0"/>
```